# How to debug laravel 5.1 in eclipse?

Tags: debugging, wamp, wampserver, laravel-5.1, eclipse-pdt

I am using eclipse as an IDE for my laravel 5.1 project running in wamp.  My question is how and/or what do I need to do to be able to debug my php application in eclipse just like how I do it when doing java in eclipse?

Thank you.

Sura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're after would be XDebug for eclipse.

The documentation for it and how to set it up is on their site, http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug.

Note though that it isn't specifically designed for Laravel, but rather PHP in general.